# Want to store response received after a POST request in a variable which can be accessed outside inner class

Tags: java, android, post

```
 String Data;
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        System.out.println(response);
                        Data = response;

                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        { //code for POST parameters
            }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I get the error `Variable 'Data' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.`

The problem is, if I do declare the String as final, I understandably get the error that `Cannot assign a value to final variable 'Data'` as I cannot assign a value to it again inside the class.

**Is there a way that I can store the `response` in a string, which can then be used outside the body of the classes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an effective solution here: [Global Variable Or Application Context Variable - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136).

So using a global class independent of your other files allowed me to call methods that could store the response(or JSONObject) in a variable that can be accessed and operated across all activities.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many ways to that, the most common among them is calling a method.

for example :-

```
public class A {
String responseData = null;
    public onResponseCallMe(String data){
      //do whatever you want to do with this data here
      // like saving to global variable;
      responseData = data;
    }
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this); 

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() { 
            @Override 
            public void onResponse(String response) { 
                try{ 
                    System.out.println(response); 
                    onResponseCallMe(response);

                } catch (Exception e){ 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { 
                error.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
) { 
    @Override 
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    { //code for POST parameters 
        } 
};
queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: yes, always. :) Just don't forget to write this method in parent (outer)  class.

Comment: I have some issues with your solution. First off, I had the understanding that all `StringRequest` objects had a specific set of parameters. `StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,  
                                        "http://ave.bolyartech.com/params.php",  
                                        createMyReqSuccessListener(),  
                                        createMyReqErrorListener())`
What you are suggesting would require adding an additional one, which I don't think is correct.

Comment: I am not asking you to put it inside `StringRequest()` instead write it inside the method which initialized `StringRequest` object.

Comment: Updated my answer, to show how it will look in your code.

Comment: No, it didn't. It still was showing error. But, when I put the method outside `onCreate` I could access it outside, but only within the method. Not in the rest of the body of the class like I wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113125/discussion-between-dave-ranjan-and-maus).

Answer (score 0):

Declare `String Data` in parent class because you are declaring `String Data` as local variable and try to access it inside method that's why it is asking to make it final , and you can not change the value of final varible

Comment: add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Declare **String Data;** globally. We can't assign values to variables with Final keyword.